# Switch outlets to permanently hot. Switch to control new recessed lights

Tags: receptacle, recessed-lighting, old-work

I have a small room with one switch outlet and 3 Hot outlets on the same circuit. The work is old and ungrounded. I’m looking to make the switched outlet permanantly hot and use the switch location to control 4 new recessed lights. I will be replacing the switch with a dimmer, replacing the outlet with a tamper-resist GFCI. Any help or brief walk through of what to do would be helpful. Here’s the situation:

Switch to the right inside door:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvQOP.jpg]

Switched outlet to right of switch
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/elfIY.jpg]

Hot outlet to the right of switched outlet
[image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJBhp.jpg)]

Comment: On the switched outlet, are both sockets switched or just one ?

Comment: Yes both are switched

Answer (score 2):

You are in luck for making the outlet always hot. It looks to be wired as a simple switch loop.

The only change required to make the outlet always hot is to separate the existing wirenut and replace the black on the outlet with the black that was pigtailed.

You hadn't given any details of how you expect the switch location to control the new lights but if it is wireless or you will fish a new cable to the switch you can pigtail white to white and black to black in the outlet location to get a neutral and live to the switch location for power from that circuit. Make sure to remove the electrical tape marker on the white that marked it as a live.

Comment: Thank you Ratchet freak. Yes I intended to power the switch from this circuit and fish a wire up to the lights. What happens to the neutral white that is wire nutted to the hot black after I replace the black going to the outlet? Do I connect all 4 wires to the currently switched outlet? Will that then bring power to the switch to which I can wire the lights?  Thanks again

Comment: The white wire pigtailed with the black is not a neutral, it is a hot. The black it's paired with is the source hot. The white is spliced into it to take power up to one pole of the switch. Then, the other black wire brings the power back down to the outlet from the second pole of the switch.  Inside the outlet box, wire the blacks together and a third black pigtailed to the outlet. Then do the same with the whites. This will give you a constant power at the outlet and provide a hot and neutral to the switch box. The neutral will be "spliced thru" to the lights, the black will go to the switch

Comment: I rewired the outlet. So that the incoming hot and neutral from the upstream “always hot” outlet are connected. I then removed the wire nut coming from the switch and connected those two wires to the other neutral and hot on the outlet. This worked to remove the outlet from the switch and make it Hot. To see what would happen I flipped the switch and it threw the breaker. Does this make sense? Had the switch been connected to lights would it have worked and co tiniest the circuit and not tripped the breaker?

Comment: Thank you CLwhoops. I just read your post. I will try this.

Comment: @J.Johnson what happened when you flipped the switch is that you shorted the live to neutral, which of course will trip the breaker.  Until you are ready to make the connection to the light it's best to disconnect the wires from the switch and cap them individually.

Comment: I don't advocate trying out different electrical combinations to see what works.  Hot and neutral should ALWAYS be separated.  Remember, every neutral is white, but not every white is neutral.  I think seeing the white and black wired together in the previous configuration is throwing you off.  When you are done, you should have 3 black wires in a wire nut (source hot, hot going to the switch, and hot pigtailed to the outlet) and 3 white wires in a wire nut (source neutral, neutral going to switch box, and neutral pigtailed to the outlet).

Comment: Alternatively, place the two black wires in the box to the brass outlet screws and the two whites to the silver screws.  This will accomplish the same thing as the pigtail method, I just prefer to use pigtails for various reasons.  In the switch box (the one that formely controlled the outlet), separate the black and white and cap them for now.  You can connect them when you add the lights.

Comment: @clwhoops44

Can I not add updated pictures In the thread? I wire nutted the blacks and whites together and pigtailed third wires from each to the outlet. This again made the outlet perm. hot and Unswitched. Does it make sense now that when I flip the switch (which connects to nothing) it shorts the circuit. Apologies for my naïveté this is my first dabble into electric. 

Thanks again!

Comment: If the black and white in the switch box are connected together (or placed on the switch terminals), then yes, it make sense.  Separate those two and cap them individually.  I do not know about adding pics, I'm new here too...

Comment: The white wire in the switch box was formerly used as a hot, not a neutral.  Now that you've made changes in the outlet box, the white is a neutral wire so when you flip the switch, hot contacts neutral and shorts the circuit.  Remove the wires from the switch screws and cap them individually.

Comment: About using wirenuts or screw terminals, since the OP said they were going to install a GFCI he should definitely use the line and load terminals on the receptacle. In the j-box that  formerly was switched it appears the hot set is the set on the left, connect those to the line, the set that goes to switch connect to load. This will GFCI protect the circuit extension. The other hot outlet may be a location a GFCI may protect the formerly switched receptacle, but we don't know if it is circuited that way.

Comment: Thank you all. Because it appears that my switched outlet was the last one on the circuit in the room, it is my understanding that I should replace the FIRST outlet in the room with GFCI, and replace the following outlets with basic tamper-resist 3-prong.

Comment: Why are you putting GFCI in here @J.Johnson?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  please correct me if I am wrong but it is my understanding that the best “quick” way to update the circuit is to put a GFCI outlet first in the chain. This will help safeguard the outlet and following outlets against electrocution and shorting....

Comment: @J.Johnson -- I'm asking if there's an actual *need* for GFCI protection here (say due to an outlet being near water) or if it's just an "extra"